# Wordpress with wp e-commerce add_action() not working

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I'm trying to add an function to be run when the payment is successful.

The [documentation](http://docs.getshopped.org/category/developer-documentation/) for wp e-commerce says there is a hook for this called [wpsc_payment_successful](http://docs.getshopped.org/documentation/wpsc_payment_successful/).

But nothing happens when I try to do this:

```
function do_stuff() {
    echo "Hello World";
}
add_action('wpsc_payment_successful', 'do_stuff');
```

This code is in functions.php

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to output something on this hook. According to the doc you linked to the hook fires just before the user is redirected.

Comment: But I should be able to do some database and api calls?